# Improper integral of $\int_0^a \frac{ \phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}dx$ exists by using $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}=\phi'(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

Suppose that $\phi$ is a $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ function.
I am reading a statement that claims
$$c.p.v. \int_{-a}^a \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}dx = \int_{-a}^a \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}dx.$$

It states that since $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x} = \phi'(0),$ the integrals $\int_{-a}^0 \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}dx$ and $\int_{0}^a \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}dx$ exist and finite and consequently the two integrals are equal.

However, I am not sure how we have $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{\epsilon}^a \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}dx$ exists from the derivative result.

The best  I could think of is
by the Mean Value Theorem, we have
$|\phi(x)-\phi(0)| \le |x| \max_{x \in [-a,a]} |\phi'(x)|$.
Hence $|\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}|\le \max_{x \in [-a,a]}|\phi'(x)|$. And we have
$$|\int_{\epsilon}^a \frac{ \phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}dx|  \le \max_{x \in [-a,a]}|\phi'(x)|\int_{\epsilon}^a dx = (a-\epsilon) \max_{x\in [-a,a]}|\phi'(x)|.$$

But I don't know how to prove the existence of the limit and what it converges to. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you know measure theory in particular dominated convergence?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes I do but when we deal with improper integrals aren't we dealing with limits of Riemann integrals?

Comment: For each $\epsilon>0$ the integral is a proper Riemann integral and coincides with the Lebesgue integral. You might want to call it an "improper Lebesgue integral", but in this case it is a standard Lebesgue integral that can be treated with DCT: the function $(\phi(x)-\phi(0))/x$ defines a $L^\infty$ (hence $L^1$) function on $[0,a]$, and $\unicode{x1D7D9}_{x>\epsilon}( \phi(x)-\phi(0))/x \to ( \phi(x)-\phi(0))/x $ a.e. on $[0,a]$. For worse functions, one cannot simply delete "cpv" from the left hand side, and you really need an improper Lebesgue integral